# Cómo puedo dibujar una línea en un control usando gradientes

Tags: c#, windows-forms

He visto que el espacio de nombres **System.Windows.Media** posee clases como
**LinearGradientBrush**, **RadialGradientBrush** , las cuales por lo ke vi me permitiria dibujar usando gradientes, el problemas es que para dibujar sobre un control uso la clase Graphics la cual posee entre sus funciones una llamada DrawLine que recibe como primer parametero un objeto **System.Drawin.Pen** al cual le puedo pasar un **Brush**, pero ahi es donde surge el problema que a pesar de que LinearGradientBrush hereda de una clase **Brush** no es precisamente la misma que la que paso al constructor de la clase **Pen**.

Por ejemplo si deseara dibujar una linea de color negro en un formulario tendria que hacer lo siguiente.

```
public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Creo una instancia de la clase Graphics para poder hacer las operaciones de dibujo
    Graphics g = createGraphics();
    /*Creo el pincel con el cual se va a dibujar, normalmente puedo hacerlo usando
      Pens.Black o sea Pens.{Color} pero utilice new SolidBrush para que vieran el uso de la
      clase Brush de la que hablaba arriba*/
    Pen pen = new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.Black));
    //Dibujo una línea horizontal desde X=0 hasta X=10 en el borde superior del formulario
    g.DrawLine(pen, new Point(0,0), new Point(10,0));
}
```

Comment: Hola. ¿Sería posible que incluyeras un __[mcve]__?

Answer (score 0):

Encontré la solución aki [Multi-color linear gradient in WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7822514/multi-color-linear-gradient-in-winforms)

La solución era usar la clase LinearGradientBrush del espacio de nombre **System.Drawing.Drawing2D**